# Oracle cost based и оптимизация запросов

Tags: oracle, sql

Доброго времени суток. Пытаюсь развить свои навыки оптимизации запросов, которые близки к нулю, и имею, так сказать, мучающий вопрос. Если оракл использует стоимостную оптимизацию, то какой смысл изменять структуру запроса (выстраивать список таблиц в условии FROM, задавать порядок соединения и т.д.), с целью оптимизации, если так или иначе план будет перестроен в соответсвии со статистикой?

Answer (score 1):

Используйте подсказки (hints) оптимизатору, если cost based не устраивает.
Вот тут почитать можно http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14211/hintsref.htm#i8327